# ProtoBuf, inheritance and generics

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Given the following code:

```
[Serializable, ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(ValueA))]
[ProtoInclude(101, typeof(ValueB))]
public class Value
{
}

[Serializable, ProtoContract]
public class ValueA : Value
{
}

[Serializable, ProtoContract]
public class ValueB : Value
{
}

[Serializable, ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1000, typeof(ContainerA))]
[ProtoInclude(1001, typeof(ContainerB))]
public class Container<T> where T : Value
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public T Item;
}

[Serializable, ProtoContract]
public class ContainerA : Container<ValueA>
{
}

[Serializable, ProtoContract]
public class ContainerB : Container<ValueB>
{
}
```

I get an error when trying to serialize ContainerA/ContainerB:

> ProtoBuf.ProtoException : Known-type
>   ContainerB for ProtoIncludeAttribute
>   must be a direct subclass of
>   Container`1

Commenting out one of the following lines - so that only one class inherits from Container - will make ProtoBuf happy again:

```
[ProtoInclude(1000, typeof(ContainerA))]
[ProtoInclude(1001, typeof(ContainerB))]
```

What's going on here an what can be done about it?

TIA

Comment: Which version of protobuf-net is that btw? Just wondering why the message is a bit screwy...

Comment: Closed generic types aren't really directly inherited from their *open* generic definitions - it is a bit more convoluted. Can you clarify what it is you are trying to model? Or does the code illustrate it all?

Comment: Hi Mark! The code accurately illustrates the problem I'm having, but in order to understand what's going on in "reality" I should have written "public List<T> Item;" instead of just "public T Item;" (although in the real code we're having one more inheritance level there too). So we're modeling different kinds of "time series", where we can have some different kind of "time series values" - if that makes anything clearer?

Comment: ...and maybe I should mention that all classes contains code and properties - they are not simply empty as shown above

Answer (score 1):

I'm still waiting for more info, but ultimately inheritance from the open-generic type is a bit tricky. Perhaps if I understand the exact model I could add more, but the following works:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using ProtoBuf;
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(ValueA))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(ValueB))]
public class Value
{
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ValueA : Value
{
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ValueB : Value
{
}
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Container<ValueA>))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Container<ValueB>))]
public abstract class Container
{

    public abstract Value BaseValue { get; set; }
}
[ProtoContract]
public class Container<T> : Container where T : Value
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public T Value { get; set;}

    public override Value BaseValue
    {
        get { return Value; }
        set { Value = (T)value; }
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var model = new Container<ValueA>();
        model.Value = new ValueA();
        var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(model);
        Debug.Assert(clone.Value is ValueA);
    }
}
```

although actually the relationship between `ValueA` and `ValueB` is entirely unnecessary unless you need it:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using ProtoBuf;

[ProtoContract]
public class ValueA
{
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ValueB
{
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Container<ValueA>))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Container<ValueB>))]
public abstract class Container
{

    public abstract object BaseValue { get; set; }
}
[ProtoContract]
public class Container<T> : Container
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public T Value { get; set;}

    public override object BaseValue
    {
        get { return Value; }
        set { Value = (T)value; }
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var model = new Container<ValueA>();
        model.Value = new ValueA();
        var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(model);
        Debug.Assert(clone.Value is ValueA);
    }
}
```

Comment: Marc, has something changed since reply date? Closed generics in the end of hierarchy are often useful, but seems it's still not serialized with ProtoBuf.net - though there is no error as in original question, I still get Null in    public T Value { get; set;} from Container<T> .